# Wireshark - you don't have permission to capture on that device mac

Tags: macos, permissions, wireshark

I installed Wireshark and during the installation it showed an error but the installation itself completed. When I ran the program and tried to capture packets on my network, it showed this error:

[image: You don't have permission to capture on that device]

I'm new to mac so i don't even know how to properly ask.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

According to User: [gmale's answer on ask.wireshark.org](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/578/mac-os-cant-detect-any-interface), he solved his problem in this way and I'm sure that it could solve yours as well. It says:

1- **Open Terminal**

2- **Type 'whoami'** or Copy and paste this command To see your exact **user name**:

```
whoami
```

(for me that was **AliGht**)

[image]

3- Now **execute the following commands:**

```
cd /dev
```

> And grant your username admin access:

```
sudo chown YourComputerUsername:admin bp*
```

and enter your **computer password**, if it is your first time, then it is normal in Unix command line or cmd to not see the passwords you type in the cmd, due to the security of your computer:

[image]

4-  **now type this command for to find bp:**

```
ls -la | grep bp
```

The last command will display a list of files such as:

[image]

5- Make sure all of them have your **user name** and **admin** as the user/group. For some reason, the **last one didn't get assigned properly so I had to run the command**:

```
sudo chown YourComputerUsername:admin bpf4
```

so the last command fixed my problem as you see in the last image:

[image]

**Done!**

**If your WireShark is open then close it and open it again.**

All credits of this tutorial goes to user [gmale on ask.wireshark.org](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/578/mac-os-cant-detect-any-interface),

**If you want to open WireShark always as administrator then take a look to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42574321/3618481) which I created a shortcut for it via Applescript, and this is the only way which you can open the WireShark always as administrator even when you turn off/on your mac.**

Comment: For some reason I'm getting this error each time I restart my computer, any idea what could be the cause of the problem? I installed Avast to remove a browser hijacker, could Avast be rolling back the ownership on those files?

Comment: No Avast has nothing to do with this, just take a look to the another post which I created at the bottom of this post, the only way is that you always run the WireShark in Admin, and you actually can't give an app a full permission due to the security reasons, so you need to open it every time as Admin, just take a look the post which I created a shortcut for the wire shark via Apple Script. Good luck :)

Comment: I would not recommend changing any file or folder permission's with in any system folder like /dev/.  It will bight you at some point.

Comment: @Apps4U Since we're adding the current user that has Admin privileges then there's no problem specially in this case.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me with this short version of your answer: 
`sudo chown "$USER":admin /dev/bp*`.

Comment: If anyone is very new to unix, don't actually use AliGht in your command. Use your own username found via `whoami`

Answer (score 46):

I don't know how to solve this problem, but if you want a temporary fix, you can use the following command:

```
$ sudo /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/Wireshark
```

Comment: Not really the best option while will work, I would do the option above, ```sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a `whoami` -t user access_bpf``` as that will fix. Now I would not change any owners within the /dev file path either

Comment: And then make an alias for that in your .bashrc.

Comment: Although this is the easiest solution the usage of wireshark with root privileges is discouraged: https://wiki.wireshark.org/Security

Answer (score 12):

Wireshark provides the solution itself, along with the explanation of weird secrets:

1. add your user to the group "access_bpf" by commanding
   `` sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a `whoami` -t user access_bpf ``
2. then launch Wireshark's script
   `sudo "/Library/Application Support/Wireshark/ChmodBPF/ChmodBPF"`;

That's all, because (as the script explains):

```
# Unfortunately, macOS's devfs is based on the old FreeBSD
# one, not the current one, so there's no way to configure it
# to create BPF devices with particular owners or groups. BPF
# devices on macOS are also non-cloning, that is they can
# be created on demand at any time. This startup item will
# pre-create a number of BPF devices, then make them owned by
# the access_bpf group, with permissions rw-rw----, so that
# anybody in the access_bpf group can use programs that capture
# or send raw packets.
```

Comment: ```$ sudo "/Library/Application Support/Wireshark/ChmodBPF/ChmodBPF"
:36: resource busy: /dev/bpf1
:36: resource busy: /dev/bpf2
:36: resource busy: /dev/bpf3
:36: resource busy: /dev/bpf4```

Comment: @John I'm getting similar warnings, too, along with Wireshark working.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to open WireShark always as administrator I suggest to use AppleScript:

Open AppleScript: By pressing **cmd+space** and write **AppleScript Editor** in the **Spotlight Search** as picture below:

[image]

Then from **File** --> Choose **NEW**

[image]

In the open window write:

```
do shell script "/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/Wireshark" ¬
    with administrator privileges user name "username" password "password"
```

Change the "username" and "password" with yours. If you don't know your username in terminal write "**whoami**" to see your username, password is your computer password!.

Mine is look like this:

[image]

Now export your script as Application, by going to --> File --> Export , and change File Format to **Application** write a name for your file and Save it on your desktop like following pictures:

[image]

[image]

**DONE** now run your App from Desktop, and by this way your WireShark runs always by **Admin Permission**.

Comment: If you don't want to save your password in script, you can use as `do shell script ¬
 "/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/Wireshark" with administrator privileges`

Comment: Doesn't work here. A dialog pops up, asking for "Where is X11?"

Comment: @decades You need to install Xquratz then, usually its installed by OS, don’t know why you don’t have it! Anyway check this link and install it: https://www.xquartz.org

Comment: Well I have Xquartz installed, otherwise WS wouldn't pop up. Anyway, don't bother. I have installed the latest WS version now and the problem is gone entirely

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same problem in MacOS High Sierra (v10.13.6). I have clean-up all dependency files and folders but nothing works for me.

Using the terminal, if I run the following command then it is working -

```
sudo chmod o+r /dev/bpf*
```

Comment: This solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/Wireshark
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue and then notice below document provide solution already.

---

https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChBuildInstallOSXInstall.html

2.5. Installing Wireshark under macOS
The official macOS packages are distributed as disk images (.dmg) containing the application bundle. To install Wireshark simply open the disk image and drag Wireshark to your /Applications folder.

In order to capture packets, you must install the “ChmodBPF” launch daemon. You can do so by opening the Install ChmodBPF.pkg file in the Wireshark .dmg or from Wireshark iself by opening Wireshark → About Wireshark selecting the “Folders” tab, and double-clicking “macOS Extras”.

The installer package includes Wireshark along with ChmodBPF and system path packages. See the included Read me first.html file for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Run the application from **the terminal** with the following command:

```
User$ **sudo Wireshark**
```

Wireshark should open and packet capture should work then.

Answer (score 0):

Was having same issue with install and run permissions etc. Attempted a few of the above mentioned fixes and although they would come back with the desired result program still would not run properly even with uninstall/install in addition.Getting a bit overwhelmed with it not working after several remedies being attempted I came to one that was super simple and worked -

I simply set up/checked log in as root user. Here you can enable/disable root user account, enable log in account and change root password. So I just switched profiles from my Admin account to the Root account. (I am honestly not sure if its safe to do it this way, so thinking many of you have far more knowledge on this than me I'd appreciate your comments on that!) Also my understanding is that you cannot properly run sudo commands if root account is enabled - So probably just tuning it off if it were on would suffice, but I wanted a quick and easy install at that point. The steps are really easy:

support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012

Then just switch user accounts to root -Log in with "other" then type root and your password.

Now just install Wireshark and it should install and run properly! 
**I don't think I would stay in root account after install.

Hope maybe this will help some!

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to modify my folder permissions on my system device files like the accepted answer, but I was able to get permissions by opening Wireshark like this:

```
sudo /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/Wireshark
```

Bonus, you can add an alias to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
alias ws="sudo /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/Wireshark"
```

Now execute the file: (or you can open a new terminal window)

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Open wireshark with super user permissions:

```
ws
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn’t get Wireshark working on my iMac 24” with macOS Ventura 13.3.1 and an M1 chip.

I think the first problem was that I installed the Arm version instead of the Intel version. So I fixed that and it still wasn’t working.

Then I disabled the Little Snitch app, which installed a Content Filter as seen under Settings: Network: Filters & Proxies, and Wireshark suddenly worked.